# How to Hide iframe when Internet is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am making an app with web view inside of it which handles offline html pages. One html page contains contact and Rating review. I would like to show the Rating review inside an iframe from where user can review the items but when internet is not availaible instead of showing no connection availaible. I would like to hide the iframe or instead show an image or default html page.

Is this possible.
I tried the below link but it doesn't work for me.
[if there is no internet connection, hide iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131585/if-there-is-no-internet-connection-hide-iframe/20131615#20131615)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is an article to help you out: https://davidwalsh.name/detecting-online

Comment: @MilanChheda would it very easy if any example or how to implement the solution would be posted. Everything I learned, all credit goest to stack overflow...so when new things comes...I get stuck and this is completely new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<any url you prefer>",
    timeout: 10000,
    error: function(jqXHR) { 
        if(jqXHR.status==0) {
            alert(" No connection");
        }
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("Connectivity");
    }
});
```

Or you can try downloading some file into your server to check connectivity, without using ajax.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 if (! window.jQuery) {
 alert('No Connection !!');
  }
 else {
 // internet connection established
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extremely simple example to help you out. Save this as HTML and open in your browser with internet connection ON and with internet connect OFF:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    alert(navigator.onLine)
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

If `navigator.onLine` gives you `true`, means internet is working fine.

Comment: But does ’navigator.online’ reliably reflect actual online status in all browsers? The answer is NO.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Strange. This one says, it works. https://caniuse.com/#feat=online-status