# How to check user has internet connection, using angularJs

Tags: angularjs

When an user attempts to log in without Internet connection, I just need to check whether he/she is connected to internet or not.

I tried the following code :

```
if (status == '404') {
    $scope.error="No internet connection";
    return false;
}
```

But this status 404 comes even when my Web Service failed to connect. I need to differentiate both, if is the user's internet connection issue or the Web Service connection issue.

Comment: You can use `navigator.onLine` javascript function or write a service for this, check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine), since it's just a dirty test to check connection, you can also [mock an AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2384227/1431600).

Comment: @EvandroSilva: it works some, some time not..if disable network it works, if i disconnect my wired internet connection it won't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Using `navigator.onLine`

You can use `navigator.onLine` and wrap it on a helper variable, like this ([Credits to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242703/1431600))

```
myApp.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
      $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = false;
        });
      }, false);
      $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = true;
        });
      }, false);
});
```

and then watch it in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch('online', function(newStatus) { ... });
```

**But** that just serves as a dirty check to know if the PC is actually connected to a *network*, not meaning that the internet is working.

## Using a fake AJAX request

You can mock a service that does a fake request to a browser (**warning: non-tested code below**)

```
myApp.service('Internet', function($http){
  this.IsOk = function () {
    return $http({ method: 'HEAD', url: '/' + window.location.hostname + "/?rand=" + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) })
    .then(function(response) {
      var status = response.status;
      return status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
    });
  }
});
```

And then use something in this context:

```
myApp.controller('TestController', function(Internet){

  Internet.IsOn().then(function(isok){
    if(isok) {...} else {...}
  });

});
```

Code for request mocking in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384227/1431600).

Also note that it will not work using `localhost`, because the server will work even when disconnected to the internet.

Comment: Why those response codes though? 200 through 300 and 304?
I'd have thought some 4X codes would also be applicable, eg 404

Answer (score 2):

Taken from MDN's summary of [NavigatorOnLine.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine).

> Browsers implement this property differently.
>
> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local
>   area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions
>   return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when
>   it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value
>   necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You could
>   be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is
>   running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters
>   that are always "connected." Therefore, if you really want to
>   determine the online status of the browser, you should develop
>   additional means for checking. To learn more, see the HTML5 Rocks
>   article,  Working Off the Grid.
>
> In Firefox and Internet Explorer, switching the browser to offline
>   mode sends a false value. All other conditions return a true value.
>
> You can see changes in the network state by listening for the events
>   on window.onOnline and window.onOffline.

You can access that information via `window.navigator.onLine`, but as the documentation states, it's very inconsistent cross-browser.

You can also listen for changes in status using `window.addEventListener` as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {alert("offline");})

window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {alert("online");})
```

Comment: it works some, some time not..if disable network it works, if i disconnect my wired internet connection it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JavaScript property, `navigator.onLine`, it returns a `Boolean` value that specifies wether the browser is in **online** mode or **offline** mode.

The `navigator` object contains information about the user's browser.

It is supported in all major browsers, so you sholdn't have any problem at all.

Comment: If by *supported by all major browsers* you mean [this inconsistant behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13076434/542251) then...