# Socket.io error message showing up while disconnect internet

Tags: angularjs

How to get disconnect error message while internet connection is lost via angular & socket.io

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post relevant snippet of your code and exact error message. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `navigator` function for this. `navigator.onLine` will return true, if internet is connected otherwise it will return false,

Then bind its value to `$rootScope` as

`$rootScope.online = navigator.onLine`

You can use `$watch` to check it if internet disconnects.

Comment: If u have the source code for this task. could u please share with us. so i can match easily. still not done

Comment: @Ankur try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121369/how-to-check-user-has-internet-connection-using-angularjs
And accept my answer if it works :)

Comment: Please check this scrip is this ok....

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var log = document.getElementById("log");

  function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

    status.className = condition;
    status.innerHTML = condition.toUpperCase();

    log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "Event: " + event.type + "; Status: " + condition);
  }
  window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
});